# Can't the user which is executing the program access the not permissible files if the SETUID is set?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, setuid

I have two users first being `ace` and the second being `ej`

ace has a file in its home directory, which is a shell script, with the following permission set ( setuid i have used )

```
-rwsr--r-x 1 ace ace 15 Jan 20 05:18 /home/ace/myshellscript
```

the content of script is very simple, listed following

```
echo "`whoami`"

cat ./testPrevEsc
```

but if I try to read another file owned by the the `ace` (testPrevEsc) which I think i can do by just passing `cat filename` in the $1, i think i should be able to do it, irrespective of permission that is set for others, as long as the owner can read it, but I can't why ?

My understanding of setuid says, that the program or shell executes as its being executed by owner, instead of executing user ( ej in my case), so why cant I read the file and still getting whomai as `ej` instead of `ace` ? on the other hand doing `sudo whoami` works fine it give you root, not the user you are running, I think I'm missing something here.

Comment: FWIW, `echo "\`whoami\`"` is silly, you could just run `whoami` directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the bash interpretor doesn't have the, `setuid`, it's still running with uid of user `ej` and for doing something like this you will have to change the uid of interpretor.

Following video might be helpful - https://youtu.be/iv5gflNM7rc?si=o-Ren0ow-nmojgAk

Above video method works, only if we are concerted with taking privileges of `root`, because `/usr/bin/bash` or whatever shell you are using it will be owned by the root itself, but in our case `ace` is not root, so the way to do it is via a c program like following.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("euid is set to %u\n", geteuid());
    FILE* f = fopen("/home/ace/testPrevEsc", "r");
    if(!f){
        perror("File open failed");
        return 1;
    }else{
        int c;
        while ((c =fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        {
           putchar(c);
        }

        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

because calling `system` will set the Effective user id back to the user which doesn't have permission in our case its `ej` that's why we are getting `whoami`'s return value as `ej` and not `ace`.